# How to use a For Loop to make a triangle out output of the inputted numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

*Hello there!*

**I've been a given a Task like so:**

- Request the user to enter a number
- Check if the user input is not empty. Also, check value entered is a number
- Write on the HTML document a triangle out of the numbers as follow:

**E.g. output: (let’s say the user entered number 10)**

**Your input number is 10.**

10

11 11

12 12 12

13 13 13 13

14 14 14 14 14

15 15 15 15 15 15

- The triangle should have 6 rows.
- Use Comments explaining how the program works
- Follow Indentation for clarity purposes.

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

```js
var input = prompt("Enter a number: ");

if (input.value == '' || input.value == input.defaultValue) {
  alert("Either you entered a NaN or you left an empty field. \nPlease enter some number!");
}

for (input = 10; input <= 15; input++) {
  var a = '';
  for (var j = 10; j <= input; j++) {
    var a = a + '' + input;
  }

  document.writeln(a + "<BR>");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Task Write your Own Code</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Task Write your Own Code</h1>


</body>

</html>
```

- First of all, my **IF** statement is not working properly even if **I input a string or don't leave a blank input field** - the alert message still pop up;
- And the result of document.writeln still printed even after alert pop's up with inputted string or empty field;

Please, someone, help me to solve this task or at least tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of the `.value`.  `input` **is** the value.

Comment: `input` is going to be a string, not an actual input element so does not have a `value` nor `defaultValue` property. Hence your second condition is actually `undefined == undefined` which is always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [`window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).

Remove `.value`.  `input` **is** the value.

Also, you aren't telling your code to **not** run if `input` is "bad".

```js
// Be in a function so that you can return
(function() {

  var input = prompt("Enter a number: ");

  if (!input) {
    alert("Either you entered a NaN or you left an empty field. \nPlease enter some number!");
    // Get of of the function
    return;
  }

  for (input = 10; input <= 15; input++) {
    var a = '';
    for (var j = 10; j <= input; j++) {
      var a = a + '' + input;
    }

    document.writeln(a + "<BR>");

  }
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. really appreciate it! I've just started with JavaScript so still trying to practice and sometimes just confused about some sort of things!

Answer (score 0):

`|| input.value == input.defaultValue` makes no sense since there is no such thing as `input.defaultValue` and, even if there was, you only need to check for an empty string. Also, `input` is already the response from the user so `.value` isn't needed.

You need to add an `else` condition to your `if` statement because even if no number is entered, your code will continue to do the looping.

Additionally, `document.write()` is only ever used in rare situations where you are building a new document from scratch, dynamically. It should not be used just to update an existing page's content. Instead, prepare an empty element ahead of time and when ready, update the content of that element.

Your loop configurations were a little off as well.

See other comments inline:

```js
// Get the user's response, converted to a number
var input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number: "), 10);

// Get a reference to the waiting output area on the page
var output = document.getElementById("output");

// Check that a number was given
if (!isNaN(input)) {
  // We have a number...
  // You know you need to go 6 times
  for (x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
    var a = '';
    // And then you need to go however many times the outer loop is on
    for (var j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
      a += input + ' ';  // You just need to write out the current input value
    }
    input++;  // Increase the value
    
    // Update the output area on the page
    output.innerHTML += a + "<br>";
  }
} else {
  // We don't have a number:
  alert("Either you entered a NaN or you left an empty field. \nPlease enter some number!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Task Write your Own Code</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Task Write your Own Code</h1>

  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And, if and when you get more into `String` operations, you'll find that you don't even need the inner loop:

```js
// Get the user's response, converted to a number
var input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number: "), 10);

// Get a reference to the waiting output area on the page
var output = document.getElementById("output");

// Check that a number was given
if (!isNaN(input)) {
  // We have a number...
  // You know you need to go 6 times
  for (x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
    // Set up the string to be written and then just repeat that 
    // however many times the outer loop is currently on.
    output.innerHTML += (input + " ").repeat(x) + "<br>";
    input++;  // Increase the value
  }
} else {
  // We don't have a number:
  alert("Either you entered a NaN or you left an empty field. \nPlease enter some number!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Task Write your Own Code</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Task Write your Own Code</h1>

  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and your time!

Comment: @AlexM It is customary to up vote all helpful answers and to mark one that has answered your question as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out on how to upvote. I'll definitely upvote the helpful answers!